# When does the IntoIterator implementation for mut Vec get invoked?

Tags: rust

The `Vec` type has an implementation of the `IntoIterator` trait for mutable vectors:

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut Vec<T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    type IntoIter = slice::IterMut<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> slice::IterMut<'a, T> {
        self.iter_mut()
    }
}
```

I am not able to get that code invoked. I am trying:

```
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
for mut i in &vec {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

What usage of `Vec` will invoke that particular `IntoIterator` implementation?

Comment: I think you should call directly wiht _vec.into_iter()_. You don't need to have the vec mutable for that, and even the item _i_ don't need to be mutable, as you're going to have ownership of the vector's items.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Have added an answer to my own question.

Comment: `mut Vec<T>` is not a type. There is an implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&mut Vec<T>`, and one for `Vec<T>`, as well as the one for `&Vec<T>` which is the one you are calling in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will invoke the `IntoIterator` variant mentioned in the question:

```
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
for i in &mut vec {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

This is because the `vec!` macro returns an owned `Vec`, not a reference. You can mutably iterate over the owned `Vec` using `for i in &mut vec`.

Comment: The `vec!` macro returns an owned vector, not a reference. You can mutably iterate over the owned vector `vec` using `for i in &mut vec`.

Comment: Updated the answer with the info you provided.